# Post Parameter to other Server

Tags: php, curl, xampp

I want to send parameters to an api with php curl .content type is xml but when i send this parameter i got an error like :

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_MUTE - assumed 'CURLOPT_MUTE' in C:\xampp\htdocs\router.php on line 20

Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\router.php on line 20
```

My curl code is :

```
$xml_data ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'.
'<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'.
    '<soap:Body>'.
    '<getMassBarcode xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">'.
    '<UserName>username</UserName>'.
    '<Password>password</Password>'.
'<PostNodeCode>19387</PostNodeCode>'.
'<CityCode>1</CityCode>'.
    '<TypeCode>11</TypeCode>'.
    '</getMassBarcode>'.
'</soap:Body>'.
'</soap:Envelope>';


$URL = "http://poffice.post.ir/webbarcode/getbarcode.asmx";

        $ch = curl_init($URL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml_data");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

How can i fix that?

Notice : i used post man to test that api . in postman raw option and i put that xml content. it worked great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using a later version of curl. Just removed that line from the code and it should work for you.

Here from the [curl setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) page it is written:

> Removed in cURL 7.15.5 (You can use CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER instead)

Comment: i removed `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);`  but not work